# Fody, propertychanged and setting same value?

Tags: fody-propertychanged

Is there any way to configure fody to not check the value which is set to property - I have situations when value is the same and I want property to be set because I have additional logic in property setter that is not invoked.

Comment: Same problem... ended up with the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implementation.

Answer (score 4):

*This is clearly literally years after the original question but for future reference:*

This is indeed possible by modifying the options in the `FodyWeavers.xml` file.

As is shown on the PropertyChanged.Fody [wiki](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Options), one of the options is called `CheckForEquality` and can be set to false (it defaults to true). This will prevent Fody from injecting equality checking code. The `FodyWeavers.xml` file could now look as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <PropertyChanged CheckForEquality='false'/>
</Weavers>
```

As noted in the comments there is also the possibility to do this per property via the DoNotCheckEquality attribute e.g.

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person 
{
    [DoNotCheckEquality]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

See [wiki/Attributes](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Attributes)

Comment: There is also attribute DoNotCheckEquality that can be set per property